# ORACLE SQL Get Daily Data look like calendar

Tags: .net, oracle, vb.net

Make calendar by sql, using this query

```
SELECT 
        NVL(MIN( DECODE(TO_CHAR(dates,'D'),1, TO_CHAR(dates,'DD')  ) ),' ') Sunday
        ,NVL(MIN(DECODE(TO_CHAR(dates,'D'),2, TO_CHAR(dates,'DD')  ) ),' ') Monday
        ,NVL(MIN(DECODE(TO_CHAR(dates,'D'),3, TO_CHAR(dates,'DD')  ) ),' ') Tuesday
        ,NVL(MIN(DECODE(TO_CHAR(dates,'D'),4, TO_CHAR(dates,'DD')  ) ),' ') Wednesday
        ,NVL(MIN(DECODE(TO_CHAR(dates,'D'),5, TO_CHAR(dates,'DD')  ) ),' ') Thursday
        ,NVL(MIN(DECODE(TO_CHAR(dates,'D'),6, TO_CHAR(dates,'DD')  ) ),' ') Friday
        ,NVL(MIN(DECODE(TO_CHAR(dates,'D'),7, TO_CHAR(dates,'DD')  ) ),' ') Saturday
FROM(
    SELECT TO_DATE(:yyyymm,'YYYYMM') + (LEVEL -1) dates
    FROM dual
    CONNECT BY LEVEL <= EXTRACT(DAY FROM LAST_DAY(TO_DATE( :yyyymm ,'YYYYMM')))
) t
GROUP BY DECODE( TO_CHAR( dates, 'D'),1, TO_CHAR( dates, 'IW')+1, TO_CHAR( dates, 'IW') ) 
ORDER BY DECODE( TO_CHAR( dates,'D') ,1, TO_CHAR( dates, 'IW')+1, TO_CHAR( dates, 'IW') );
```

An I have quantity. Table like this.

[image]

Is it possible to view daily data in calendar format?

I mean look like this.

[image]

Beacuase I have to make calendar and data to GridView(Devexpress 15.2).

I can't use the scheduler control, because of my client request.

So, I plan to query the data in the database in calendar format.

Is it possible?

If not Is it better to query the only daily data(not calendar format) in database and then make calendar format in .NET code?

my database is oracle19c and .Net is 4.5

Comment: "Is it better to query the only daily data(not calendar format) in database and then make calendar format in .NET code?" Yes probably. You're not going to get the ideal design coming from just the database. You would always have to do some GUI work after the data arrives.

Comment: This sounds more a topic for .net rather than Oracle SQL. Maybe see https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/378900/Calendar-NET or https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/736ca4/showing-date-events-in-Asp-Net-calendar-control/ or https://github.com/Martin-Pucalka/WPF.EventCalendar I would expect you can find a library in nuget.

Comment: Another one: https://aspnet.daypilot.org/calendar/ and https://github.com/esausilva/ASP.Net-EventCalendar - Google for "event calendar"

Comment: thank you. I make calendar in .Net, query just only get quantity data.